# How to open a .eps plot generated from RStudio using Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, eps

I have generated several .eps plots from RStudio while performing some data analysis and I have saved the .eps files to my computer. However, when I try to open the .eps files, the program that starts is Adobe Illustrator which successfully opens the file, but the text in the graphs looks really odd. I would like to re-open the .eps files in the default graphics viewer that comes with RStudio rather than use an external program to open them. Can anyone provide information on how to do this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using eps? I don't believe the Rstudio viewer can open arbitrary eps files (or other pre-rendered images). The RStudio plot panel is a plot device. It draws the data to the screen based on primitive draw commands from drawing functions; it does not render existing graphics files. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in RStudio. I use ghost script viewer.

Comment: @MrFlick No reason in particular. The script I was using defaulted to exporting the files in .eps, I've since changed it to export .jpeg instead. I figured if the RStudio plot panel is able to display the plot when I first create it, and if it generates the .eps file it should be able to open it again. I guess not.

Comment: @DanLewer Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check out ghost script viewer.